# ISNULL wildcard '%' search returning no records

Tags: sql-server

As one of the criteria of a WHERE clause in a search query in SQL Server, I'm trying to search by courseId using ISNULL.

When the query is executed with all null values except for @currentUserId, as below, the query returns no records.

My SQL:

```
    DECLARE @currentUserId int = '6'
    DECLARE @searchString nvarchar(MAX) = NULL
    DECLARE @courseId nchar(10) = NULL
    DECLARE @dateFrom date = NULL
    DECLARE @dateTo date = NULL


    SELECT [questionId],[Question].[moduleId],[questionDate],[questionTopic]
    FROM [dbo].[Question],[dbo].[Module],[dbo].[ModuleCourse]
    WHERE [lecturerId] = @currentUserId AND

    ([dbo].[Question].[moduleId] = [dbo].[Module].[moduleId] AND
    [dbo].[Module].[moduleId] = [dbo].[ModuleCourse].[moduleId]) AND

    ([dbo].[Question].[questionTopic] LIKE ISNULL('%' + @searchString + '%','%') OR
    [dbo].[Question].[questionText] LIKE ISNULL('%' + @searchString + '%','%')) AND

    [dbo].[ModuleCourse].[courseId] = ISNULL(@courseId,'%') AND

    ([dbo].[Question].[questionDate] >= ISNULL(@dateFrom,(SELECT MIN([questionDate])
                                                                FROM [dbo].[Question])) AND
    [dbo].[Question].[questionDate] <= ISNULL(@dateTo,(SELECT(GETDATE()))))
```

When the line

```
    [dbo].[ModuleCourse].[courseId] = ISNULL(@courseId,'%') AND
```

is commented out, results return as expected.
([dbo].[ModuleCourse].[courseId] is PK; nchar(10))

It seems as though the wildcard % does not work in this situation; I have no idea why.
Please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `@courseId` is null, you will be comparing the `courseId` to the string `'%'`. The `=` operator doesn't use wildcards.

You can use `like` instead of `=`, or write the condition as:

```
(@courseId is null or [dbo].[ModuleCourse].[courseId] = @courseId) AND
```

Comment: Hi Guffa, the LIKE still returned nothing but the condition clause returned correct results as expected. Many thenks; I think I literally lost hair over this one..

Comment: @user1748443: Ah, you also have a problem with the `nchar(10)` data type, the expression `ISNULL(@courseId,'%')` doesn't return `'%'` when `@courseId` is null, it returns it padded with spaces to the length 10. You might want to use `nvarchar(10)` instead.